# jquery mobile input types

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile.I am displaying button using

```
<input type="button" id="result" value="" onclick="datedisplay()">
```

when i click on this button i want to chage the value of button like

```
document.getElementById('result').value=""+results.values.join(' ');
```

`results.values.join('')` will contains a string value.

I want to display that value when the user click on this button.
It is not working when i am using jquery mobile framework.
when i use normal html i am able to display like this.
And i am not even able to adjust the width,background and font size of button.

Default css only applying when i tried to use my style.Can any one help me how to customize buttons overriding the css of jquery mobile when i need.

Comment: This `document.getElementById('result').value=""+results.values.join(' ');` has nothing with jQuery so your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jquery mobile you can use jquery to setup a click handler for the button:

```
$('#button_id').live('click', function() {
    $('#result').val('Set Value Here');
});
```

If you are using onClick="[Javascript Code]" you should change to a click handler like the above example or change the href attribute of your link to:

```
href="javascript:[Javascript Code];"
```

Because Jquery Mobile does not keep onclick when it styles your button.

To learn about Jquery Mobile CSS I recommend using FireBug for Firefox or something similar that will show you DOM elements after they have been rendered by JQuery Mobile. Jquery Mobile takes your links with data-role="button" and turns it into several span tags.

For example:

```
<a href="#some_link" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Some Link Text</a>
```

Turns into:

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-role="button" href="#some_link">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Some Link Text</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: how to set the size of the button,and the font  size on the button

Comment: I have not tried to change the font-size but you can add padding to the link (style="padding:15px") to make the link larger after jquery mobile renders it. I would assume you can do the same for font-size (style="font-size: 20px;").

Comment: I just checked and this updated the font-size and added padding around the text: <a href="#" data-role="button" style="padding:15px; font-size:30px;">TEST TEXT</a>

Comment: href="javascript:[javascript code];" didnt work for me..I am using some other plug in for iphone datepicker which has some methods.i need to call that method when i click on that button.I dont know how to sync with jquery syntax.k instead of button i am using div on clicking it i am able to display the result value. I need one more help  i want to use background image instead of theme colors for header and footer.can you tell me how can i acheive it

Comment: You can use css to add a background image for the header and footer: div[data-role="header"] {background-image:url(IMAGE_URL_HERE);} ... and you can change header to footer for the footer background image

Comment: thank you..worked.i gave like this <div data-role="header" style="background-image:(url)" data-position="fixed">it didn't work.